# What is best way to store user data in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cookies

I want to be able to store a user's id in my Android app so whenever the user accesses my app I can retrieve information that identifies the user and create a custom page for the user.  I do this with cookies in javascript on my website but what is the recommended way in Android?  SQLite or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, [See the Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Shared Prefs may be what you want for this but if you are going to store other data with the id's then you may want to consider using a SQLite DB.

Shared Prefs can store data in a ("key", value) pair so they can be a good fit for this type of situation

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I just want to store the user's id so I can use it to access my internet database to get the user's name, etc.  I think Shared Prefs is the way to go.  Being a newbie I want advice from those who have more experience.

Comment: You're welcome. This is really just a preference choice but it does sound like shared prefs will work fine for what you want

Answer (score 4):

Android provides an `AccountManager` that is the most complete, robust, and correct way to deal with user authentication and preferences. [The documentation explains it well.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

A more lightweight solution is to [save things in `SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)